# ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False

Tags: python

I am trying to load an array of image set which is already loaded in the drive by colab I am using python. But I get the error `'ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False'` How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code that produces this error? please add code snippets

Comment: i think you need to add  `allow_pickle=True` parameter.